# Exceptions, failed deploy when using Gemfire source with SpringXD

Tags: java, spring-xd, gemfire, geode

I have the following stream definition in SpringXD:

```
stream create dataListener --definition "gemfire --regionName=data --useLocator=true --host=lithium --port=10334 | null" --deploy
```

But it gives me the following errors, and it marks as 'failed':

```
    [error 2015/04/09 16:09:20.265 ART  <poolTimer-client-pool-2> tid=0x59] Unexpected error in pool task <com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.LiveServerPinger$PingTask@5a422dfd>
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.PingOp.execute(Lcom/gemstone/gemfire/cache/client/internal/ExecutablePool;Lcom/gemstone/gemfire/distributed/internal/ServerLocation;)V" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/xd/module/support/ParentLastURLClassLoader) of the current class, com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/client/internal/LiveServerPinger$PingTask, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/client/internal/PingOp, have different Class objects for the type p.execute(Lcom/gemstone/gemfire/cache/client/internal/ExecutablePool;Lcom/gemstone/gemfire/distributed/internal/ServerLocation;)V used in the signature
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.LiveServerPinger$PingTask.run2(LiveServerPinger.java:83)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.PoolImpl$PoolTask.run(PoolImpl.java:1197)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorWithKeepAlive$DelegatingScheduledFuture.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorWithKeepAlive.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This has happened before, and I have fixed it by restarting the VM. However, I would like to know how to fix it in a proper manner.

Any tips, workarounds or guidelines would be useful. Also, please tell me if you need more information.

I am using the latest version of Spring XD, 1.1.1, and Gemfire version 7.0.2. The locator is in the same node as the stream deployment. I also am using a singlenode topology.

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't seen that with gemfire before. v7.0.2 is what spring xd uses. The singlenode log should contain the gemfire settings, including the gemfire version, JVM version etc. This same info will appear in the locator and gemfire server logs. Please verify that the JVM and gemfire versions are all the same

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any messages in the locator/server logs ?

I couldn't reproduce your problem here, can you also share how are you starting your locator ?